# Need a Windows Server version 1709 (build 16299)

Tags: windows

I'm wanting to do some experimentation on this specific version of windows server.

I've been tasked with resurrecting an old internally developed system, and some old docs on it give mention to some specific behaviour on this server version. I was hoping to stand up a quick VM to proof the matter, so I can then determine what to do when I need to install the system on a newer OS.

According to [this](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/windowsserver/2017/10/17/windows-server-version-1709-available-for-download/) post 1709 was available on Azure, but I can no longer find it in the marketplace. (unless I'm missing something...)

I also cannot find it as a evaluation version as an iso or vhd.

Does anyone know where I can source an image for a test from ?

Comment: Presumably Azure has dropped it because it is [no longer in support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/windows-server-release-info).

Comment: I figured something like that. Bit odd that one can still get a Svr 2008 on Azure and a Svr 2012 on prem eval quite happily. Hoping there is still some way to get a copy for pure academic purposes, not prod.

Comment: Both 2008 and 2012 are still in support, so no surprises there.  As far as I know, MSDN subscriptions still include out-of-support versions of Windows, but you should of course confirm that before making a purchase, as well as checking that the licence terms will be suitable for your needs.

Comment: As developer or in admin you should have access to MSDN and Technet subscriptions which - guess what - have (also old) OS versions ready for download.

Comment: Checked the MSDN, and yes it is available there. Will incurr a full subscription to access, but it is there none the less. Please answer and ill mark it as accepted. Thanks